# From input form to C source code, check for not allowed keywords

Tags: php, c

From a html form input area, I write a C source file (using PHP 'file_put_contents'), then compile it and run it () and print results, using PHP.

But before running it, I check input data for what I consider as C prohibited words, like 'fopen', 'goto', and so. (using PHP 'strpos').

Why 'fopen' ? because I dont want the user using this form to open a PHP source file and get sensible data from it...

My question : is there a  possibility to use escape sequence ou any thing else used by hackers that would make possible to use these prohibited words ?

An extract of the actual source code :
- to compile :

```
$reponseModele = shell_exec("gcc -o source.exe source.c  2>&1");
```

- to run (with input data for 'scanf')

  $reponseTest = shell_exec("gcc -o cource.exe < data.txt   2>&1");

## Edit 1

Nothing secret in PHP source files (except database password...but not 'root' one...)

I am taking into account the fact that the security is very low, but as it is a personal web site, for education and student evaluation, risks are limited, except if user can start a massive attack from this web site...

As I told in comments, I have checks some C keywords (from your comments, I have added 'asm' 'extern', 'volatile'), loops are checked.

Something to control would be 'malloc', maybe.

The question that still keep in mind is : is there a possibility to escape characters so that 'fopen', or other keyword,  could be executed ?

## More PHP code will help

$srcprog is the main C source and I add a count( I will change the name...), $contenuTest is the code to compile :

```
$contenuTest = "static int ctz = 0; \n#include <stdlib.h> \n" . "$srcprog";
```

Then, I add loops checks (I will also change the 100 limit...) :

```
$contenuTest = str_replace("{", "{ ctz++; if (ctz>100) {printf(\"BOUCLE !!!\");exit(99);}", $contenuTest);
```

Comment: Just from the gist of it, what you are trying to do is basically akin to running an ssh server with your php's user account without a password. I mean, I can't stop you, but be warned **what you are doing is very, very dangerous!**

Comment: Supporting @DavidStockinger. A simple filter won't work, there are easy ways to work-around them, e.g. inline assembler, macro magic, etc. If it was possible to detect a program is correct and does nothing invalid, you had solved the halting problem (read about it).

Comment: As an aside: if your PHP source files themselves contain sensitive data, that also would indicate a lack of good security hygiene. Don't embed secrets in source code -- instead, make sensitive data a property of the environment, controlled by your deployment mechanisms.

Comment: @DavidStockinger and members : each user has got his own account (users are IT students), my PHP web site is not really sensible (no secrets ...), it is for student evaluation. I have check some keywords such as 'system', 'include', 'define', and so. But  I wondered if it was possible to escape letters of 'fopen', for example, and get the possibility of read files of the current directory.

Comment: @PatrickDezecache Yes, as suggested by Daniel Pryden, this is basically impossible. There are so many ways that this could go wrong, I couldn't possibly list them all in a comment, especially since Daniel already provided his fair share. My suggestion is: **Don't do it!** If you want to assess what students are doing, let them hand in their code and analyze that. Not only does this prevent malicious content, it also gives better insight in how good they are already at programming.

Comment: @DavidStockinger and members : what a shame...I was already doing assessment for sql and relational algebra, algorithmic, and C coding what the last one to do.. All results are stored in a database, and it is very easy to go through the works...Thank you for answering, I will take your recommandations !

Comment: @PatrickDezecache: For what it's worth, if you did similar implementations for "algorithmic" and "sql" then there's a pretty high chance that similar vulnerabilities already exist for those too. If you're going to be running code you don't trust 100%, then you need to be paranoid about what you allow it to do, which usually means that you need hardware and/or OS-level support to ensure you've sandboxed it effectively.

Comment: @DanielPryden : thank you for comment, for algorithmic and relational algebra, I use html form with limited input values by the user and use js to produce an xml document, then xsl to transform it into a js algorithm (to test it interactively) or a sql command. But for SQL, I use a textarea  that need to start with 'select', and that has got only one ';', and use only some tables (checked using explain)... Sorry, I am not a hacker...I would like to know a little about that to be more conscious of risks...until now, I has been a really good tool for student assessment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blacklisting words is not sufficient. There is no way to verify that the code provided by the remote user will not attempt anything malicious. There is no way to prevent malicious access by restricting the source text of the program: if you want to run untrusted code, you need operating system sandboxing (e.g. run the code inside a virtual machine, and firewall that machine off from everything else). (And even then, there's the danger of Spectre attacks against the VM host.)

To give you an idea of the dangers here: it would be trivial to write a program that constructs arbitrary bytes on the stack, and then "accidentally" returns execution to that buffer; this means that the attacker can write arbitrary machine code that gets executed directly. The compiler can't do anything about this (it might emit a warning, but those can be disabled), and no blacklisting of keywords will prevent you from being able to allocate values on the stack or return from functions, not if you want the program to be able to do anything useful.

Not to mention that there are lots of trivial denial-of-service attacks here: an attacker can just write a program that forkbombs, or consumes 100% CPU forever, or many other things that might not be explicitly malicious but that would make your server useless for any other work.

A commenter mentioned the [Halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) as proof that this approach can never work. The stronger proof is [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem), which proves that *any* non-trivial semantic property of a program is undecidable. Essentially, if you are given a piece of code and asked "does this code do X" for *any* value of X, there will always be some pieces of code for which it does do X, but you couldn't figure that out without actually executing it and seeing what happens.

Comment: Phyden : I have checked loops (for, while and do), adding a static variable (count), and checking after each '{' that the count is less than a certain value. if not, I add and 'exit'...

Comment: Thank you for alerting me ! it is shame, but...Just seen an example of what you said : https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/43574/how-is-printf-in-c-c-a-buffer-overflow-vulnerability